# How to convert a Function<int[], Boolean> to Function<Integer[], Boolean>

Tags: java, function, wrapper

I have a method `convertFunction` that takes as a parameter a `Function<int[], Boolean>` and I want to return a Function of this type `Function<Integer[], Boolean>`. The logic within the function should be the same.

```
public static Function<Integer[], Boolean> convertFunction(Function<int[], Boolean> f) {
    // I don't know what to do here
    return new Function;
}
```

I know you have to use some kind of wrapper class but I don't know how.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mre] and tell us what you’ve already tried.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Function.compose` to convert the `Integer[]` argument to `int[]`.

```
Function<int[], Boolean> isNotEmpty = arr -> arr.length > 0;
Function<Integer[], Boolean> other = isNotEmpty.compose(
    arr -> Arrays.stream(arr).mapToInt(i -> i).toArray()
);
```